# Get Products URLs in prestashop using API

Tags: c#, api, url, prestashop, bots

I am currently developing a ChatBot with .NET using Microsoft bot Framework i created list of products available and display the list in carousel using a Herocard and put a button BUY when the client click on it it takes him to the page where the product is located the problem is how can i get a products url using its id so i can put it in the button BUY

```
 List<product> c = ListProduct.GetProductList();
        List<Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Entities.AuxEntities.language> lan = new List<Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Entities.AuxEntities.language>();
        foreach (product p in c)
        {
            lan = p.name;
            foreach (Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Entities.AuxEntities.language l in lan)
            {
                ;
                List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
                cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: $"http://test.com/123456.jpg"));
                List <CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
                CardAction plButton = new CardAction()

                {
                    Value =$"i don't know what i should put here",
                    Type = "openUrl",
                    Title = "Buy"
                };
                cardButtons.Add(plButton);
                HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
                {
                    Title = l.Value,
                    Subtitle = (p.price.ToString("C", Cultures.usa)),
                    Images = cardImages,
                    Buttons = cardButtons
                };
                Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
                replyMessage.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the url below :

http://localhost:8080/prestashopdemo/index.php?controller=product&id_product="+p.id

so my code now is working perfectly

```
List<product> c = ListProduct.GetProductList();

        List<Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Entities.AuxEntities.language> lan = new List<Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Entities.AuxEntities.language>();
        foreach (product p in c)
        {
            lan = p.name;
            foreach (Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Entities.AuxEntities.language l in lan.Where(l => l.id == 2))
            {

                {

                    List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
                    cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: $"http://1234456789@localhost:8080/prestashopdemo/" + p.id_default_image + "-large_default/" + l.Value + ".jpg"));

                    List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
                    CardAction plButton = new CardAction()

                    {
                        Value = $"http://localhost:8080/prestashopdemo/index.php?controller=product&id_product="+p.id,
                        Type = "openUrl",
                        Title = "Buy"
                    };
                    cardButtons.Add(plButton);
                    HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
                    {
                        Title = l.Value,
                        Subtitle = (p.price.ToString("C")),
                        Images = cardImages,
                        Buttons = cardButtons
                    };
                    Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
                    replyMessage.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
                }

            }
```